# ASCIIDOC: adding link to index.html to all documents for quick navigation

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I am generating HTML documentation with Gradle `org.asciidoctor.convert` plugin and I want to add easy accessible link to main index document to each generated page.

From `index.adoc` I point to individual pages, like:

```
== Troubleshooting
* <<KNOWN-ISSUES.adoc#,Known issues>>
* <<monitoring.adoc#,Monitoring>>
```

but I'd like to be able to quickly navigate back to `index.html` from  any page.

My initial idea was to alter generated TOC but I can' figure out how I cad do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hackish workaround for HTML output only:

```
asciidoctor {
    attributes \
        'toc-title': '<a href="index.html">↑Go Home↑</a>'
}
```

I would be glad to see alternative solution.